# Jupyter keep returning nonetype for my digit recognition. i keep getting "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

What is the problem actually. I saved some picture that i draw with paint and saved in the same folder with the ipynb. i have named th png file as 1,2,3,4,5,6.

```py
import cv2 as cv

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)

x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)

accuracy, loss = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

print(accuracy)

print(loss)

model.save('digits.model')

for x in range(1,6):

    img = cv.imread(f'{x}.png')[:,:,0]

    img = np.invert(np.array([img]))

    prediction = model.predict(img)

    print(f'the result is probably:{np.argmax(prediction)}')

    plt.imshow(img[0], cmap=plt.cm.binary)

    plt.show
```

[enter image description here][1]

hope will get help soon
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6vTs.png

Comment: It did not find the location of the images. Check the location again or your image name

Comment: is there anything `1.png` as image name?

Comment: yes.why? i put that name as the image file name

Comment: Use `print(img)` without using any slicing. And check whether it will return anything or not

Answer (score 0):

I might hve missed the saving of the image or you did not post it here. Anyway, the path or image name might be wrong as `cv.imread` returns empty matrix if the image cannot be read. (Based on the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56))

Try to see if you can load the image first, perhaps the path is invalid.

Comment: It returns `None` if it can't load.  That's not an "empty" matrix.

Comment: Based my answer on the documentation: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56

Comment: That doc is for many languages. The python version returns the `c` Null as the `None` object.